# Git squashing fails becuase of untracked files

Tags: git, version-control

I am trying to squash commits 3 through 10 in a branch with 10 commits.

```
git rebase -i 'xyz'
```

The returned error message says: "error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: src/file1.c.orig src/file2.c.orig
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting

Could not apply abc"

-- commit abc is the first commit to contain file1.c.orig and file2.c.orig that are causing problems and that I need to delete.

I do not need file1.c.orig and file2.c.orig, and need to remove them. How can I remove them successfully so I can squash my commits?

I have tried doing

```
git rebase -i abc^
```

to remove those 2 files, but it displays the same error message. Also, I have tried to add src/file1.c.orig src/file2.c.orig to the .gitignore file, but the same error message is shown during the squash.

Comment: Type `git status`. Do you have untracked files there? They need to be stashed (`git stash`) or committed before you proceed.

Comment: You just need to keep removing the bogus files (including via `git rm` as you copy your commits) to make sure they're gone from the work-tree and from the new commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BKSpurgeon gave me the correct answer in the comments section of my question. All you have to do is

```
git add src/file1.c.orig src/file2.c.orig
```

after you try interactively rebasing, then try rebasing the same way again. The first time it fails, so it does the abort for you. The second time, it should pass.